# Is this proof of the totality of this relation correct?

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I'm currently writing an original chapter of a textbook I'm republishing and I need to know if this rather pedantic proof of a total ordering on $\mathbb{R}$ is correct. It **looks** correct, but something is still bothering me about it. I'd be very grateful if I could get a second opinion on it.

I'll post the theorem preceded by the definitions and terminology I'm using.

---

Defintion: Let R be a relation from a set A into A i.e. a subset of A × A. Such a relation is called a binary relation.  Let a,b,c $\in$ A. Then: 
a) R is called reflexive if (a,a) $\in$ R. 
b) R is called antisymmetric if when (a,b)$\in$ R and (b,a) $\in$ R, then a = b.
c) R is called transitive if when (a,b)$\in$ R and (b,c) $\in$ R, then (a,c)$\in$ R. 
d) R is called symmetric if when (a,b)$\in$ R, then (b,a) $\in$ R
e) R has the connex property if for every a,b $\in$ A, either (a,b)$\in$ R or (b,a) $\in$ R. 
f) R is called trichotomous **if exactly one** of the following conditions holds:  (a,b)$\in$ R,  (b,a) $\in$ R or  a=b. (In other words, if (a,b)$\in$ R and a$\neq$b, then  (b,a) $\notin$R. A relation that satisfies this property is called asymmetric.)

Note: It can confusing for beginners what the difference is between property (b) and property (f). These properties refer to 2 different but related relations on A. (f) is a stronger condition and it requires that condition (a) is false for any relation that (f) is true of. The classic example of a trichotomous relation is the relation “< or >“ on ℝ. Clearly this relation is anti-symmetric-for every a,b$\in$ ℝ, a < b and b < a can only be true if a = b because otherwise, we have a logical contradiction. But clearly, a < a or a >a is also a contradiction for the exact same reason. So  $(a,a)\notin R$ and the relation is not reflexive on  ℝ! So any asymmetric relation is antisymmetric, but the converse is not true. 
Now we can define some important kinds of relations in mathematics: 
Def: Let R be a binary relation on a set A. If R is reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric (properties (a)-(c)), we say R is a partial ordering on A. If A has a partial ordering and in addition has property (e), then we say A is a totally ordered set. If a totally ordered set has a second binary relation R’ on A such that property (f) holds, then we call this relation a strict total ordering on A.

We first need to state precisely what “≥” on ℝ means. Since we’ve avoided an explicit construction of ℝ beyond the brief one from ℚ given by Dresden, we’re going to state certain results proven in a detailed construction axiomatically i.e. by definition. Let’s assume ℝ with the usual arithmetic operators +  and × that you remember from high school with the usual properties of commutative, associative and distributive laws of algebra.  We also assume the absolute value as defined by Dresden in chapter 3. 
Def: We define 0$\in\mathbb ℝ $ as the unique real number such that for any a$\in\mathbb ℝ $, a + 0 = a.  We define 1 as the unique real number where 1 ≠ 0 and for every a $\in\mathbb ℝ$, 1× a = a.

Def: Let a $\in\mathbb ℝ$. Then the negative of a, denoted –a, is the unique real number such that a + -a = 0.

We now define axiomatically a unique subset of ℝ that will allow us to rigorously define “≥”. It will also eventually permit us to give a more rigorous definition of the absolute value that’s consistent with modern usage.

Def: Let x,y$\in\mathbb ℝ $.Then there exists P$\subset\mathbb ℝ $, denoted P, that satisfies the following 2 axioms:

(i) P is closed under + and × i.e. x,y$\in P$ implies x + y$\in P$ and x × y $\in P$.

(ii) For every real number x$\in \mathbb R$, either x$\in P$, x = 0 or - x$\in P$.

We can now use P, called the positive class of the reals, to rigorously define the relation “≥”. 
Def:  Let x $\in\mathbb R$. Then x ≥ 0 if and only if either x $\in P$ or  x = 0. Similarly, we say x$\leq$ 0 if and only if either –x $\in P$ or x =0.
Now let a,b,c $\in\mathbb R$.  such that c = b − a. Then c ≥ 0  $\longrightarrow $ b – a ≥ 0 $\longrightarrow $  b ≥ a. Similarly, c $\leq $0  $\longrightarrow $ b – a $\leq$ 0 $\longrightarrow $  b $\leq$ a.

Now we’ll prove the relation gives a total ordering.

1) Reflexive: Let x ∈ℝ. Then, x ≥ x $\longrightarrow $ x - x ≥ 0, which is true since x - x =0. Thus, (x,x)∈ℝ×ℝ.  2) Anti-symmetric: Let (x,y)∈ ℝ×ℝ and (y,x)∈ ℝ×ℝ. Then, x≥y and y≥x. If x=y $\longleftrightarrow $ y=x, then it’s trivial. Assume x≠y. Then either x > y  or y >x. If x >y, then x−y > 0. If y >x, then y−x >0. These cannot both be true because then because P is closed under addition, (x−y) + (y-x) >0 $\longleftrightarrow $ 0 >0, which is a contradiction. So the only time when this holds is when x and y are the same value. Therefore, x=y and the relation is anti-symmetric. 3) Transitive: Let (x,y)∈ ℝ×ℝ and let (y,z)∈ ℝ×ℝ. Thus, x≥y and y≥z. If x≥y , then either x−y $\in P$ $\longrightarrow $  x−y > 0 or  x−y =0. Similarly, if y≥z , then either y−z $\in P$ $\longrightarrow $ y−z > 0 or  y-z =0. We now check each possible case. If x−y$\in P$ and y−z =0, then y=z and x−z $\in P$, so x≥z.  Similarly, if y−z $\in P$  and x =y , then x−z $\in P$ , so x≥z.   Clearly if x= y = z, then x =z and (x,z)∈ ℝ×ℝ. There is just one case left to check: if x >y and y > z. If so, then x –y $\in P$  and  y – z $\in P$ . By closure of P,  (x –y) + (y – z) = x – z  $\in P$ . Thus,  x≥z. Therefore, (x,z)∈ ℝ×ℝ in all cases and transitivity is proven.. We lastly have to prove the connex property i.e. that for any x,y  ∈ℝ, (x,y) or (y,x) ∈ℝ×ℝ. Let’s prove it by contradiction. Assume neither ordered pair is in the relation. Then x < y and y < x, which is clearly impossible. So at least one of these ordered pairs has to be present. So the relation is comparable and is therefore a total ordering on ℝ! Q.E.D

---

Edit: I've gone back and cleared up all the MathJax text as best I can. I'm gonna check it carefully against the original Microsoft Word document, but it looks correct. 
I'll be very grateful to whoever responds.

Comment: "*I'm currently writing an original chapter of a textbook I'm republishing...I don't really have time to put the whole thing in proper math text*"  If you were writing the book with LaTeX it would be simple copy-paste into mathjax for the most part.  The massive number of characters not being displayed correctly is incredibly distracting, not to mention the lack of formatting and white space.

Comment: Many of the symbols your software uses apoear only as a rectangle.

Comment: I wasn't writing it in Tex, which is a VERY bad habit I need to get out of. I'll edit it, but I really need someone to proofread the proof for me after that.

Comment: "In other words, if $(a,b)\in R$ and $a\neq b$, then $(b,a) \not\in R$. A relation that satisfies this property is called asymmetric." If $(a,b) \in R$, how could $a\neq b$ be false?

Comment: Fabio Somenzi  Fabio Somenzi It can be false if (b,a) is also in R and (b,a) = (a,b) by the equality of ordered pairs and by definition then, the relation is symmetric because then (a,b) is in R iff (b,a) is in R. Right?  unless I'm missing something. Am I? – Mathemagician1234 5 mins ago

Comment: All I'm saying is that if you say a relation trichotomous if **exactly one** of $(a,b) \in R$, $(b,a) \in R$, $a=b$ holds, then if $(a,b) \in R$ you know that **both** $a \neq b$ and $(b,a) \not\in R$.

Comment: I had a slight error I just fixed and I'm hoping that'll clear part of this up. My main point above is that trichotomy is a stronger condition then antisymmetry because it precludes reflexivity.

Comment: The use of $>$ is rather sloppy since you have only rigorously defined the $\ge$ symbol.  You never specify whether $a>b$ means "not $b\ge a$" or "$a\ge b$ and $a\ne b$.  Similarly referring to the relation “< or >“ is extremely misleading, since you're talking about two relations.  Taken literally, the relation "< or >" is the essentially the same as "$\ne$".

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment.

I prefer definitions to use "iff" , not "if" because in almost all cases in almost all books, that is what is actually meant. I think you should include quantifiers. I think you should delete the word "called". E.g.

$R$ is reflexive iff $\forall a\in A\,(\, (a,a)\in R)$

or: $R$ is reflexive iff $(a,a)\in R$ for all $a\in A.$

I think you should not  label the properties as a), b),c), etc., because you are also using these letters for members of $A,$ which makes it harder to read and to digest.

I think Symmetric and Anti-Symmetric should be listed consecutively.

Two simple examples  of a transitive $R$ (property c)) without Trichotomy (property f)) are (1): $R=A\times A$  when $A$ has more than 1 member, and (2): $R=\emptyset \ne A.$

Many books say a relation "satisfies Trichotomy" so perhaps you should mention that this means the same as  "Trichotomous".

Comment: Thanks for the comments and I'll keep them in mind when doing the final revision. But still gets me no closer whether the proof is correct.

Comment: I disagree with the first comment. I think it's kind of extraneous to always use "iff" in definitions, and in the vast majority of texts I've seen, the "only if" is implied but omitted. So we have "$x$ is real if $x\in\mathbb R$" and never "$x$ is real if and only if $x\in\mathbb R$".

Answer (score 1):

Just a few comments.

1) It would be clearer just to define directly
"$x\geq y$ iff $x=y$ or $x-y \in P$ "
(and avoid  $c\geq 0 \rightarrow a-b\geq 0 \rightarrow a \geq b$ since I don't understand what these arrows mean )

2) A weird thing is that the order depends on $P$. The set $P$ satisfying the listed properties is unfortunately not unique (just apply to it a element of the infamous group $Gal(R/Q)$)

3) It seems you don't use the fact that $P$ is closed under multiplication. Why require it in that case ?

Answer (score 1):

I went through your proof. I think the proof of connex property is at least not complete (especially if you want it to be completely elementary). Why does it follow that if neither $x\geq y$ and $y\geq x$ then $x<y$ and $y<x$? I don't see $<$ defined anywhere. You can add this definition and show that this is true, but I would say to be complete you need to explain this.

In general I would say the proof is needlessly complicated and tedious because of how you defined $P$. Is there a reason you define $P$ like that? If you add $0$ in $P$, it simplifies the proof a lot and makes it much more readable. 
I would do the following:
First of all define $P$:

1. $0\in P$
2. $P$ is closed under addition
3. for any $a\neq 0$: $a\in P$ XOR $-a\in P$.

Then define $x\geq y$ if and only if $x-y\in P$.

**Observation**: $-(x-y)=y-x$. This follows from the uniqueness of $-a$ and by the fact that $x-y+(y-x)=0$.

**Reflexivity**: Since $x-x=0$ and $0\in P$ we have $x\geq x$.

**Antisymmetry**: If $x\geq y$ and $y\geq x$ then by the observation above $x-y, -(x-y)\in P$ so $x-y=0$, and therefore $-y=-x$ which implies that $x=y$ (to show this observe that $x-x=0$ therefore $x-x--x=--x$ therefore $x=--x$).

**Transitivity**: If $x-y\in P$ and $y-z\in P$ the $x-y+y-z\in P$ i.e. $x-z\in P$.

**Connex**: Since $x-y=-(y-x)$ by definition of $P$ if follows that $x-y\in P$ or $y-x\in P$.

PS: As others mentioned you should also change this $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ to $(x,y)\in\geq$.

Comment: +1. Thanks for all your comments, many were quite helpful. It seems you're saying the proof is basically correct, but it's overly complicated and some points are not completely rigorous because of some hidden assumptions. Correct?

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Yes this is the gist of it.

Comment: BTW, for the record, I didn't include the additive identity 0 in the positive class P simply because that's how I was taught. No deep, dark reason.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 What I meant was whether  the fact that $0\notin P$ played some role somewhere later on in your book, so it would cause problems to change it. I still think that for presentation's sake using the "non-negative" class (son including $0$ in $P$) is better because it makes the proof more transparent and clear, but of course it's up to you to decide how you want to present it.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 And another point I wanted to make w.r.t. your presentation is when you give the definition of $P$ you should state clearly that the "or" in the last clause is an exclusive or rather than an inclusive one.

Comment: These are the kinds of minutia you necessarily have to expect to get bogged down in when you begin to put your foundations under a microscope. It's a dirty job, but somebody's gotta do it.............. Thanks for taking the time out, I really needed another set of eyes for this.

Answer (score 0):

On the very first line of the proof you write

> 1) Reflexive: Let x ∈ℝ. Then, x ≥ x ⟶ x - x ≥ 0, which is true since x
>   - x =0. Thus, (x,x)∈ℝ×ℝ.

The **"(x,x)∈ℝ×ℝ"** says nothing and should be removed. The proof of reflexivity is automatic by definition, but if you insist on proving it it should look like

For any $x \in ℝ$, blah, blah, blah, so therefore $x \ge x$. PERIOD!

Elsewhere in your proof you claim again that coordinate pairs belong to ℝ×ℝ, without adding anything that isn't already known.

Here is 'canonical' transitivity argument:

$\tag1 a \le b \implies a + u = b, \; u \ge 0$
$\tag2 b \le c \implies b + v = c, \; v \ge 0$

Adding $v$ to both sides of the (1),

$\tag 3 (a + u) + v = b + v =^{by \; (2)} c$

or

$\tag 4 a + (u + v) =  c$

Since $u + v \ge 0$ we have $a \le c$.

The antisymmetry is handled the same way - set up $\text{(1)}$ and $\text{(2)}$ and 'turn the algebra crank'.

For the connex property, you know that for ever $u \in \mathbb R$, if $u \ne 0$, either $u \in P$ or $-u \in P$. So set $u = y -x$ and see what happens.